# How to iteratively define function based on index value

Tags: python, function, lambda

I want to iteratively create a list of functions, with my desired result being `phi = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x+2, lambda x: x+3]`. The code I have here creates the same function 3 times: `phi = [lambda x: x+i, lambda x: x+i, lambda x: x+i]`, but I would like the functions to be independent of `i`. How can I 'hard-code' the value of `i` while looping?

Code I am using:

```
for i in range(3):
    phi.append(lambda x: x + i)
```

The reason I want to do it this way is because I want 3 functions, rather than 1 that depends on i.

Comment: Question is bit self-contradictory 
> "How can I 'hard-code' the value of i"
> "I want 3 functions, rather than 1 that depends on i"

Can you please clarify?

Comment: My desired result is `phi = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x+2, lambda x: x+3]`, that is, `phi` is a list of 3 different functions that are independent of `i`.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks! Fixed with `for i in range(3):
    phi.append(lambda x, i=i: x + i)`